# AppleScript reformat date

Tags: date, format, applescript

One of my variable is a date in this format "August 7th, 2016"

My system date is DD/MM/YY

how can I change the AppleScript date, and then calculate how many day from today this was?

Kind regards

Edit (date convertion)

```
set X to set {year:y, month:m, day:d} to (current date)

set convertedTime to m & d & y
```

or

```
set {year:y, month:m, day:d} to (current date)

set convertedTime to m & " " & d & "th," & " " & y
```

Update :

Whaever I do, I have Invalid date and time date june 3, 2006. Would that be because 10.11 updated applescript?

```
tell (date "june 3, 2006") to get its month as integer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if really your date "August 7th, 2016" does not match at all your regional date settings, the script bellow is parsing that date to convert each term. Of course, it would be much more efficient to match regional date setting !

```
-- date conversion without taking care of regional settings
-- assume date in in English format and returned format will be dd/mm/yy (not mm/dd/yy)
set X to "August 7th, 2016"

set D to ConvertDate(X)
log D


on ConvertDate(X) -- sub routine to convert string "english_month dayth/st, year" to real date
set MS to {"January", February, "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"}
set LW to every word of X
if (count of LW) is not 3 then return "" -- invalid format
set MI to 0 -- check month : should be in the list
repeat with I from 1 to 12
    if item I of MS is item 1 of LW then set MI to I
end repeat
if MI is 0 then return "" -- the fisrt word is not in the list of months    
try -- check day : it should be NNth of NNst
    set DI to (text 1 thru -3 of item 2 of LW) as integer
end try
if not ((DI > 0) and (DI < 31)) then return "" -- invalid day
try -- check year
    set YI to (item 3 of LW) as integer
end try
if not ((YI > 0) and (YI < 9999)) then return "" -- invalid year
return date ((DI & "/" & MI & "/" & YI) as string)
end ConvertDate
```

Comment: Well that the thing, the "August 7th, 2016" is from a website, (a variable than  Im grabbing from safari) my computer is actually in the UK regional settings.  

At the moment when I try do added or remove some day I have "Can’t get every word of 172800." number -1728 from every word of 172800" but I will have a look !  Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must first coerc your date/string format to a date. Then you make the difference with system current date -> get number of seconds which you divide by "days" using "div" operator :

```
set X to date "August 7th, 2016"
set Delta to (((current date) - X) as integer) div days
log Delta
```

Your date is August 7th and we are August 19th, then Delta will be 12 days !

Comment: thanks for your reply, try your code but have "Invalid date and time date August 7th, 2016." but I expect my date conversion to be invalid (I edited my script

Comment: To coerc your string date to a real date, the string must comply with your regional settings (system preferences / language and region / advanced / date). "August 7th, 2016" should comply with UK settings (I think !). I assume it is the case, because you get that date from somewhere else with these settings. If this is not the case and you can't change your local settings, then the only solution is to parse that string to rebuild a date. What are your regional date settings ?